# CentOS installer does not recognise usb stick

Tags: centos, system-installation

I'am trying to install a CentOS 5.6 on a relatively new machine with an ASUS Z170-A mainboard. For this I'am using an installation stick which will install a pre configured CentOS 5.6 system.

I have the following problem: I can boot from the stick and start the installer. But after that, the installer is trying to use its own driver to read the data from the USB Stick which does not work. My assumption is, that there aren't any matching driver for the ASUS Z170-A mainboard in the installer. On older machines, this works without problems.

Is there any way to bypass this dilemma? As it stands right now, the stick can't be used on newer machines.

Answer (score 0):

Its totaly normal, centos 5.x don't provides support for USB 3 that too recent. So you should try to use usb 2 port instead. Moreother if it's for a new setup, I suggest you tu use more recent version of centos (7 if recent software don't cause you any issue, 6 instead)

Comment: Ok thanks. I wanted to avoid that but it seems there is no other way.